# Should I tag python if the question is indirectly related to it?

Tags: discussion, tags

Say I have a question related to SQLAlchemy or Django and I rightly tag it with. But should the question contain a [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag aswell? Of course the aforementioned tags are tightly coupled with python but should that tight coupling be reflected in the tagging?

One more thing adding the [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag increases probability of your question getting noticed, but I believe that shouldn't be reason for adding (un)necessary tags, *just* to get noticed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of tags is to be noticed by the people that might be able to answer the question.

I'm far from a Django expert (although that is bound to change soon), but I can answer a fair number of the Django questions because they often deal with pure-python problems *in a Django context*. I don't follow the [django](/questions/tagged/django) tag, but I *do* follow [python](/questions/tagged/python).

The same goes for SQLAlchemy questions, plenty of Python experts can help out with SQLAlchemy questions.

Like the version-specific tags, [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7) or [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x); the [sqlalchemy](/questions/tagged/sqlalchemy) and [django](/questions/tagged/django) tags help to narrow things down a bit, but as long as the actual question is mostly about Python usage in that context, the [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag is applicable.

Comment: one reason why I asked this question was [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16653074/1309352). My judgment said that this should only contain the `SQLAlchemy` tag but since it wasn't gaining much attention I added the `python` tag as it was indirectly related (apparently it hasn't changed much).